# Hyperledger Fabric fails to trigger FSM event REGISTER

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

There are multiple peer nodes, a single orderer and a single CA authority for production and want to deploy the chaincode. I have the compiled chaincode and the `go` file in a directory called `chaincode-app/`

The peer node has a docker instance running with the name `peer0-vm`. I want to deploy my chaincode using this peer. When I run

```
docker exec peer0-vm peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -p chaincode-app/
```

I receive the following error:

```
2018-01-03 05:35:30.577 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
2018-01-03 05:35:30.578 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
Error: Error getting chaincode code chaincode: <go, [env]>: failed with error: "exec: not started"
```

The peer logs are as follows:

```
2018-01-02 11:00:29.826 UTC [gossip/gossip] NewGossipService -> WARN 014 External endpoint is empty, peer will not be accessible outside of its organization
2018-01-02 11:00:29.829 UTC [gossip/gossip] start -> INFO 015 Gossip instance 0.0.0.0:7051 started
2018-01-02 11:00:29.830 UTC [cscc] Init -> INFO 016 Init CSCC
2018-01-02 11:00:29.830 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 017 system chaincode cscc/(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/cscc) deployed
2018-01-02 11:00:29.830 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 018 system chaincode lscc/(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/lscc) deployed
2018-01-02 11:00:29.831 UTC [escc] Init -> INFO 019 Successfully initialized ESCC
2018-01-02 11:00:29.831 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 01a system chaincode escc/(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/escc) deployed
2018-01-02 11:00:29.831 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 01b system chaincode vscc/(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/vscc) deployed
2018-01-02 11:00:29.831 UTC [qscc] Init -> INFO 01c Init QSCC
2018-01-02 11:00:29.831 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 01d system chaincode qscc/(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/qscc) deployed
2018-01-02 11:00:29.832 UTC [nodeCmd] initSysCCs -> INFO 01e Deployed system chaincodess
2018-01-02 11:00:29.832 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 01f Starting peer with ID=[name:"fabsmbqxc-peer0.org1.example.com" ], network ID=[dev], address=[0.0.0.0:7051]
2018-01-02 11:00:29.832 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 020 Started peer with ID=[name:"fabsmbqxc-peer0.org1.example.com" ], network ID=[dev], address=[0.0.0.0:7051]
2018-01-02 14:06:22.467 UTC [chaincode] notifyDuringStartup -> WARN 021 trying to manually run chaincode when not in devmode ?
2018-01-02 14:06:22.467 UTC [chaincode] HandleMessage -> ERRO 022 []Failed to trigger FSM event REGISTER: transition canceled with error: peer will not accepting external chaincode connection name:"chaincode-app:1.0"  (except in dev mode)
2018-01-02 14:06:22.467 UTC [chaincode] processStream -> ERRO 023 []Error handling message, ending stream: transition canceled with error: peer will not accepting external chaincode connection name:"chaincode-app:1.0"  (except in dev mode)
```

On a quick read, I understood that the [chaincode cannot be executed by the user](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/2cab745abf031d8ff5d3e8f4fa7a5e5af8907fad/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go#L277-L281) and should be instead done by the peer. Can someone point out how I could deploy this chaincode?

I've tried to follow the lifecycle of `package -> install -> instantiate -> upgrade` and tried to package the chaincode before signing and installing using the command but failed.

```
docker exec peer0-vm peer chaincode package -n mycc -v 1.0 -p chaincode-app -s -S ccpack.out
```

Could someone point out where I am going wrong and a possible solution?

Answer (score 1):

`The peer node has a docker instance running with the name peer0-vm. I want to deploy my chaincode using this peer.`

Running CLI install from the peer container won't work.

If you are using docker to execute CLI you should use containers built from `hyperledger/fabric-tools`. The `e2e_cli` samples under `fabric/examples/e2e_cli` is a good reference for all this. In particular do take a look at how the CLI is constructed in `docker-compose-cli.yaml` please.

There may be other issues but this would be the first one to fix to make sure install works.

Comment: You can obviously use the `fabric-tools` image or `dev-chaincode-docker` images to do the required chaincode installation. My question is different, spinning up an fabric cluster on azure provides the required VMs with the required docker images running on it. However, the error is because `chaincode cannot be executed by user` and should be packaged and signed before being deployed. The problem here is the packaging process of the chaincode before installation.

Comment: There are two models : "devmode" where the user starts the chaincode and non-devmode where the peer starts the chaincode. You are attempting to start the chaincode in non-devmode - basically mixing the two modes. 

Suggestion would be to install the chaincode first and let the fabric manage it for you in the azure env. Devmode is intended only during dev phase for faster turnaround.

Comment: @user8209696 I assume running commands like `peer package` and `peer install` corresponds to dev mode. What would be the method to deploy chaincodes in non-dev mode?